# R: Overwrite a variable in parent namespace

Tags: r, variables, namespaces

How does the function `setMeZero` has to look so that the following would be possible?

```
a = 1
b = 2
setMeZero(a)
setMeZero(b)
a == 0
# TRUE
b == 0
# TRUE
```

edit: I really intended it this way, whether it is *good* way or *not* is another question.

Comment: This one? `a=2; foo <- function(x) {x <- 0; return(x)}; a <- foo(a); a==0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
setMeZero <- function(x){
  nm <- deparse(substitute(x)) 
  assign(nm, 0, parent.frame())
  invisible()
}
a <- 1
b <- 2
setMeZero(a)
setMeZero(b)
a == 0
# TRUE
b == 0
# TRUE
```